# How do I check a dynamic_cast is successful when returning it from a function?

Tags: c++, inheritance, vector, polymorphism, unique-ptr

I have a class which holds a vector of unique_ptrs, this class is to simplify polymorphism for me. I am trying to make a function which casts the base type to the derived type, but I can't work out how to pass back a value which I can then check to ensure it has worked (similar to if(dynamic_cast<>()...)

```
template <typename T>
class Vector_UniquePtrs {

public:
    template<typename U>
    U& DynamicCast(size_t i) { 
        return dynamic_cast<U&>(*m_Items[i]); 
    }

private:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>> m_Items;
}


Vector_UniquePtrs<Base> v;

if(auto a = v.DynamicCast<Derived>(0)) { // want to do something along these lines
    // success
} else {
    // fail
}
```

What is a nice way of achieving this?
Thanks

Comment: `dynamic_cast<U&>` - _"...if the cast fails and new-type is a __reference type__, it throws an exception`..."_ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast

Comment: I don't necessarily have to pass back a reference?

Comment: If possible, you could also use `try-catch` rather than `if-else` As in, If the dynamic cast fails an exception will be thrown, which you can catch

Comment: I just feel that a try catch is not a particularly 'clean' way of doing things, feels like a bit of a hack and not that readable...

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to  return a pointer, then you can do

`if(auto* a = v.DynamicCast<Derived>(0); a)`

or the longer explicit version

`if(auto* a = v.DynamicCast<Derived>(0); a!=nullptr)`

Comment: I have not seen multiple parts within an if statement. What does that mean?

Comment: if can contain an initialiser statement https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if

Comment: Something i was not aware of! In this instance, what is wrong with if(auto* a = v.DynamicCast<Derived>(0)) ... ? (without the a) It compiles fine for me

Comment: @MaxPeglar-Willis Hmm, I did not notice that either. If I am reading the reference correctly, you already had the correct solution :D `if(auto x = ...)` is equivalent to `if(auto x = ...;x)`.